# Light flicker sound

Tags: sound-effects, sound-design

Hi all,

currently working on a project and i'm in need of a fairly simple sound but one that I just can't seem to find or create that fits. It's the sound of a standard everyday light bulb flickering on and off before fading out completely. I can only seem to find the sound of neon lights flickering on and off and they're a little too buzzy for what I need. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Try some small splattery sounds eg drop of water into hot wok, then process through glass impulse response (like Fokke Can Sannes free Claustrophobia IRs - the glass jar) to impart the light bulb tonal quality

http://fokkie.home.xs4all.nl/IR.htm

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest looking for very light, thin, but slightly resonant metallic clicks and building it out of those.

Answer (score 0):

Get some fuzzy hum into a wavetable and play it over the keyboard, you'll probably find a nice note that resonates nicely. Then touch it up some filtering and reverb to place it properly.

That would be my guess mate

Answer (score 0):

The  Fokke Can Sannes free Claustrophobia IRs look really great! Thanks for the link